# Adding Redis Node without service restart

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm attempting to extend the elasticity feature of adding/removing a node to an existing for a Redis cluster (Non clustered mode) that AWS's Amazon ElastiCache offers to my application.  Ideally, I would like to prevent any service interruptions or have to restart the application for the updated endpoint list. I'm using the StackExchange.Redis package and I don't see a way to add or remove an endpoint from an existing connection multiplexer.

What I'm trying to accomplish is putting the endpoint values in AWS' Parameter Store so the application can reload the values when a message is sent to a subscription that the application is listening for.  Once that message has been received by the application I'm building out a new connection object, setting up all of the event handlers to the new connection and replacing the static property the application is using by wrapping the static object in a lock block while I change the connection.

**PSEUDO Code**

1. Pull array of objects from Parameter Store
2. Loop through each object in the array and add to the endpoint collection for a new StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions object
3. Set a local variable to the existing static connection object
4. Set the static connection object to a new StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer object passing in the new StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions object
5. Reassign all of the subscriptions to the new connection
6. Reassign all of the events to the new connection
7. Lock and reassign the static database object StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase that is used by the save and get methods to the new connection's handle to the database that is being used.

Is there a better way to accomplish this with the StackExchange.Redis package?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way at the moment. There are a few non-official pull requests / variants that support Sentinel : http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/redis-sentinel/